# How to apply partition on the table to get first data of each month?

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

```
CREATE TABLE employee
(
    joining_date date,
    employee_type character varying,
    name character varying ,
  typeid integer
);
insert into employee VALUES
    ('2021-08-12','as','hjasghg', 1),
    ('2021-08-13', 'Rs', 'sa', 1),
    ('2021-08-14','asktyuk','hjasg', 1),
  ('2021-09-12','as','hjasghg', 1),
    ('2021-09-13', 'Rs', 'sa', 1),
    ('2021-09-14','asktyuk','hjasg', 1),
  ('2022-08-02','as','hjasghg', 2),
    ('2022-08-03','as','hjasghg', 2),
    ('2022-08-04', 'Rs', 'sa', 2),
    ('2022-08-05','asktyuk','hjasg', 2);
```

I want to obtain the columns containing reading of first data of each month for different typeid.

I have tried applying partition but I can't seem to extract the correct data.

```
 with cte_a as
    (select row_number() over (partition by typeid order by joining_date asc) sno, * from employee)
    select * from cte_a where sno = 1;
```

I expected results from date `'2021-09-12'`,`'2021-08-12'`,`'2022-08-02'`, but I only got `'2022-08-02'`,`'2021-08-12'` in final result.

Comment: You could add extract(month from joining_date) or add date_part('month', joining_date) to your partition clause. Or use distinct on as already answered, see https://dbfiddle.uk/gdwW9upk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/XKns-Pjh)

You could use `DISTINCT ON` in combination with `date_part()` function

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (typeid, date_part('month', joining_date))
    *
FROM employee
ORDER BY typeid, date_part('month', joining_date)
```

1. `date_part('month', ...)` "normalizes" the date to the first of a month (or cut the day part, if you like)
2. `DISTINCT ON` returns the first of all ordered groups, in that case the group of `typeid` and your normalized date